# Debugging java process crashing in native code

Tags: java, debugging, gdb, native, remote-debugging

I have a java process which is exiting at some point when calling native code (JNI), I have no access to native sources. I have tried to enable error file and verbose logging, but for some reason it does not create the file, not in the directory I have specified, not in current directory. STDERR has this:

```
java: /sbcimp/run/pd/boost/64-bit/1.61.0_gcc4.8.2_cxx11/include/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:168: SOME FUNCTION: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

I tried to attach with `gdb` but it never stops anywhere. I tried to break at `exit`, `_exit`, `abort` - every time I resume process from java remote debug it seems to be hanging. After I quit from `gdb` it regretfully dies. Is this something to do with java remote debugger?

Any help would be appreciated.